# Match number string by regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am not very good at regular expressions. Can somebody help me with this?

```
$string = '1,2,3,4,7,8,10,11,14,17,18,19,22,23,26,29,30';

preg_match('/(\d*,*)(2,)(\d*,*)(4,)(\d*,*)(8)/', $string);
```

All the time this string has to be string, can't be array or anything else. Let's say I am looking for numbers 2, 4, 8 (but not 18). I am using PHP and the `preg_match` function.

Comment: you could then do a foreach loops and compare the values against whatever you wish

Comment: robert - you didnt try to answer, i have my own reasons to keep it in string

Comment: @mesnicka, quite often people asking questions here already have a solution in mind while there is a more straight forward way to solve it (which they're not aware of). If you have your own reasons, I recommend you edit your original question and explain *why* you want to use `preg_match` instead of splitting/exploding the string. Otherwise, others may keep recommending other ways to solve it.

Comment: A very wise person once said: `"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."`.

Comment: @webarto, definitely true for this question.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov 337k, the horror you've seen cannot be described with words, or regex :)

Comment: @webarto, oh no, I have seen much worse than this (if this could be any consolation to the OP :-)), believe me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution with array:

```
// explode a string to array of numbers
$haystack = explode(',', $string);
// define numbers to search
$needle = array(2,4,48);
// define found elements
$found = array_intersect($needle, $haystack);
// print found elements
if ($found) {
    print 'Found: ' . implode(',', $found);
}
```

And solution with preg_match:

```
// add "," to the beginning and string end
$string = ",$string,";
// define pattern to search (search for 14, 19 or 20)
$pattern = '/,14|19|20,/';
// if pattern is found then display Hello
if (preg_match($pattern, $string)) {
    print 'Hello';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
<?php
    $string = '1,2,3,4,7,8,10,11,14,17,18,19,22,23,26,29,30';
    $search = array(2, 4, 8);
    $parts = explode(",", $string);
    array_flip($parts);
    foreach($search as $n){
        if(isset($parts[$n])){
            echo ("found ".$n."<br/>");
        }
    }
?>
```

EDIT: With a simple "hack", you can now use an "easy" preg_match():

```
<?php
    $string = '1,2,3,4,7,8,10,11,14,17,18,19,22,23,26,29,30';
    $string = ','.$string.',';
    $search = array("2", "4", "8");
    foreach($search as $n){
        if(preg_match("#,$n,#", $string)){
            echo "found $n <br/>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: @mesnicka if you add ',' to the beginning and the end, you can search for ',$number,' wich makes the regex much easier to write ("#,$n,#") :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '1,2,3,4,7,8,10,11,14,17,18,19,22,23,26,29,30';
$search = array('2', '4', '8'); # or $search = explode(',', '2,4,8');

foreach($search as $number)
    if (strpos($string, $number) === false)
        echo $number, ' not found!';
```

> Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is
>   contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they
>   will be faster.